# NestJS mock nested module

Tags: nestjs

Im struggling mocking a module in NestJS.

I think I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

I have this `app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UtilsModule } from './utils/utils.module';

@Module({
  imports: [UtilsModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And inside the `UtilsModule`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { EmailModule } from './email/email.module';

@Module({
  imports: [EmailModule],
  exports: [EmailModule],
})
export class UtilsModule {}
```

And for last the `EmailModule`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter';
import { environment } from '../../config/environment/environment';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        host: environment.email.transport.host,
        port: environment.email.transport.port,
        secure: false, // TODO: upgrade later with STARTTLS?
        auth: {
          user: environment.email.transport.auth.user,
          pass: environment.email.transport.auth.pass,
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        from: '"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: __dirname + '/templates/',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [{ useClass: EmailService, provide: Emailer }],
  exports: [Emailer],
})
export class EmailModule {}



import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AnyObject } from '../types/types';

export abstract class Emailer {
  abstract sendEmail(to: string, subject: string, template: string, context: AnyObject): Promise<void>;
}

@Injectable()
export class EmailService implements Emailer {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(EmailService.name);
  constructor(private mailerService: MailerService) {}

  async sendEmail(to: string, subject: string, template: string, context: AnyObject): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await this.mailerService.sendMail({
        to,
        // from: '"Support Team" <support@example.com>', // override default from
        subject,
        template: `./${template}`,
        context,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      this.logger.error(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is prevent my smtp server send emails while testing. Just mock the sendEmail answer and that is it.

In my tests I have a tear up that seems like this

```
@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: EmailService,
      useValue: {
        sendEmail: () => true,
      }, // mock
    },
  ],
})
class TestModule {}
  const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule, TestModule],
  }).compile();
```

But after I a lot of tries and different setups all I had is that the smtp server is being called anyway

Does anyone knows why?

I'd tried many things I found on nestjs website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you can just override the EmailService by using .overrideProvider and  .useValue in your TestingModule

Comment: the problem seem to be your Utils Module and App Module is using the original Email Service. the service isn't overrides. you can print log to check if it is correctly override

Comment: its not overriding and the .overrideProvider not working too

Comment: have you rebuild the project while doing new Testing?

Comment: just import AppModule, and   using .overrideProvider and .useValue before compile